# Why does plotting of overlying lines in R have an effect on the plot quality?

Tags: r, plot, pixel

I've noticed that plotting of plot elements more that once will cause a noticeable change in quality. I.e. a line or points plotted on top of themselves will usually thicken the line and appear more pixelated. Does anyone have an explanation for this? Below is an example of this phenomenon in a `png` output, but similar results can be found on other graphical devices. I would have expected that since these objects should be perfectly aligned, that there should be no visible effect.

#### Example:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 20
x <- runif(n)
y <- 10*x + rnorm(n)
fit <- lm(y ~ x)

png("01_line.png", width=2, height=2, units="in", res=400, type="cairo")
par(mar=c(2,2,1,1))
plot(x,y, t="n")
points(x, y)
abline(fit)
dev.off()

png("10_line.png", width=2, height=2, units="in", res=400, type="cairo")
par(mar=c(2,2,1,1))
for(i in seq(10)){
    if(i == 1) plot(x,y, t="n")
    points(x, y)
    abline(fit)
}
dev.off()
```

Here is a closeup comparison of the single line (left) versus the 10 line (right) versions:

[image]

Comment: If you look closely at the `01_line` file, you see that the area between the circles is not white, but a light gray. If you add light gray 10 times, you get black.

Comment: @shadow - That makes a lot of sense. Why don't you provide that as an answer below.